# How to specify coordinates of a point in a matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I make that when I plot a function (based on a np.array) certain values have their coordinates in the plot?
I know how to change color and other little things with code lines like:

```
line1, = plt.plot(t, f, '*-', label='force', color='#4F81BD')  # blue
line2, = plt.plot(t, a, 'o-', label='acceleration', color='#C0504D')  # red
```

but for example if I have a "peak" in the plot line, I don't know how to make their coordinates to appear in the same plot

Comment: What do you mean "make their coordinates to appear"? Do you mean xticks on the axis? a special marker? A text tag? Something else?  Maybe add an illustration of what you're aiming for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This code snippet might help you:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y=[1,1,1,2,10,2,1,1,1,1]
line, = ax.plot(x, y)

ymax = max(y)
xpos = y.index(ymax)
xmax = x[xpos]

#Labeling the graph (ymax+1 is defining the distance from the word to the point)   
ax.annotate('local max', xy=(xmax, ymax), xytext=(xmax, ymax+1))

ax.set_ylim(0,20)
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

I hope I could help you out a bit.

Comment: maybe I'm being exaggerated but OP explicitly says that plot is based on a `np.array`, so I think you must use it instead of `list`

Comment: You are not exaggerating. Thanks for mentioning that. The above code is indeed not working with 2D, 3D etc. arrays (e.g. [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]). But I guess you can modify the code to your likings.

Comment: That actually was very helpful, thank you both